# How to insert a draw box in my html code?

Tags: html

I'm creating a web page, and I can't (with html code) add a draw box*?

*It's a box, like a Microsoft Paint, only with one brush, where the user make a draw by a click draged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no simple way to do what you want to do.  The current version of HTML (4.01, I believe) does not support this at all.  HTML 5, which is still in development, has a <canvas> element that can be used with javascript to create the kind of thing you are looking for, but only the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari support it.

See: w3schools.com/tags/html5_canvas.asp for an explanation of the <canvas> element and dev.w3.org/html5/spec/#the-canvas-element for the full (uncompleted) specs.

See: http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example1.html for an example of the kind of design you are looking for.

Comment: *Only* Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari? You've covered all the major browsers except our old friend IE! As for "latest", I'm pretty sure that Safari has had Canvas since v2 (and it's currently v4)...

Answer (score 4):

The following links may be helpful:

- [Doodle, A Demo Drawing Program](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column20/index.html)
- [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [DojoX](http://dojotoolkit.org/projects/dojox)
- [Canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_(HTML_element))

Also, have a look at this Stack Overflow thread: [Drawing on top of an image in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304804/drawing-on-top-of-an-image-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

There's no HTML element that's a "draw box". You'll need to find something built in JavaScript/Flash/Java and drop it into your page.

Try [CanvasPaint](http://canvaspaint.org/) or this other [Canvas Painter](http://caimansys.com/painter/).