# "Draw" on top of an image in HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a web-app that will users mark-up images by "drawing" on it with their cursor.    We'll take the users drawings and send it to the server to be converted to PNG or some other format for storage.

We need this app to work on both desktop- and tablet-based browsers, so Flash, Java, & Silverlight are out.  We want to support IE8+, FF, Chrome, & Safari.  Is there any type of Javascript library that will offer up some form of primitive MS-Paint-like drawing capabilities so I can send that data to the server?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304804/drawing-on-top-of-an-image-in-javascript) is similar, but I'm looking for something that'd encode organic, human gestures, not draw them out.

(And no, creating native apps for each different mobile platform is not within our core competency or budget, so that's not a viable alternative).

Comment: You'll be asking your users to "Draw Something" huh?

Comment: @Mike - Yes.  Could be display an image of a contract, and they can sign with a finger, or highlight a paragraph.  Or show a picture of a building and they can circle a portion of it.  The idea is to let them just "finger paint" on a tablet, then save their markup back on the server.

Comment: @MikeRobinson i guess that one slipped past him :)

Comment: *whoosh* Yup.  My caffeine level is dangerously low apparently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use the html canvas element or use SVG library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) e.g. http://ianli.com/sketchpad/ is a library using Raphael.

Answer (score 2):

you can use vector-graphics rendering JavaScript libraries, such as [Raphaël](http://www.raphaeljs.com).

Raphaël will also support a vast range of user agents, as it renders using VML for IE (< 9), or SVG for modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, have a `<canvas/>` element overlay your `<img/>` and get the users to 'paint' into the canvas.

The paint capabilities will depend on what you need, which you didn't exactly specify, so this is as much as I can help.