# Drawing in image with angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am developing application using angular 2. In my application i am uploading images. In this images i need to mark or draw in images particular section.Is it possible with angular 2. I didn't find any solution for this. I need to draw in images just like paint application in windows.

Please help!!

Comment: you could assume that everything you can do with javascript, you can also do with angular or other frameworks. In the end, Angular is just a javascript framework.

Comment: i am asking about any possibility for this .Or any other solution for this. please suggest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324949/draw-on-top-of-an-image-in-html-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by using Canvas. Here an Example:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "canvas-component"
    ,templateUrl: "./canvas.template.html"
   
})

export class CanvasScene implements AfterViewInit,  IScene  {

    
    //Loading Canvas and Images html elements    
    @ViewChild('myCanvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('bubbleimg') bubble_img: ElementRef
   
   //Canvas Context
   ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
   
   ngOnInit() {     
      this.ctx  = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
      this.paint(this.ctx);
   }

   paint(ctx) {        
            
     ctx.drawImage(this.bubble_img, 0, 0, 70, 50);
     //FrameRate To Repaint 
     setTimeout(() => 
     {
         this.paint(ctx);
     },
     100);
   }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<canvas #myCanvas style="width:100%" >    

</canvas>

<img #bubbleimg src="assets/bubble.png">
```

**UPDATED for Angular 8+**

Replace

```html
@ViewChild('myCanvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('bubbleimg') bubble_img: ElementRef
```

to this:

```html
@ViewChild('myCanvas', {static: false}) canvasRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('bubbleimg', {static: false}) bubble_img: ElementRef
```

Read more about this feature [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8)